# Attempting to get an ANTLR grammar to follow AND/OR statements

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, grammar

I have the following input as an example of the format I want.

> (A = 'a' AND B != 'something') OR (C != 'abc*') OR (D != 'xyz' AND D
>   != 'wui')

I have the following ANTLR grammar, unfortunately it isn't working for what I need.

```
grammar Parser;

prog: expr*;
expr: LEFTPAREN expr RIGHTPAREN
    | expr (AND|OR) expr
    | LEFTPAREN equation RIGHTPAREN
    | equation
    ;
equation : identifier equality value
         | LEFTPAREN equation RIGHTPAREN
         ;
equality : (EQUALS | NOTEQUALS);
identifier : ID;
value : STRING;

LEFTPAREN : '(';
RIGHTPAREN : ')';
AND : '&&';
OR : '||';
EQUALS : '=';
NOTEQUALS : '!=';
NEWLINE : [\r\n]+ ;
STRING : ('"'|'\'') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'*'|'_'|'-')* ('"'|'\'');
ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+;
INT :   '0'..'9'+;
WS  :   [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

When I run antlr4 utility to run this

> line 1:9 no viable alternative at input '(A='a'AND' line 1:13
>   extraneous input 'B' expecting {'=', '!='} line 1:29 mismatched input
>   ')' expecting STRING line 1:34 mismatched input '(' expecting {'=',
>   '!='} line 1:51 mismatched input '(' expecting {'=', '!='} line 1:67
>   extraneous input 'D' expecting {'=', '!='} line 1:77 mismatched input
>   ')' expecting STRING

and I get this tree [image: Generated Parse Tree]

I'm still trying to understand and learn ANTLR4 but can anyone give me some pointers on getting this to work?

Comment: Did you use AND and OR or did you use && and ||? The grammar wants && and ||.

Comment: Well...I'm an idiot >_<. I forgot I did that...

Comment: I love it when its easy, though. If it bothers one to feel stupid, they should do something else than this business. You just have to laugh and go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use AND and OR or did you use && and ||? The grammar wants && and ||.